# C# - Prevent button from being clicked if position is changed via drag and drop

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am using Control.Draggable, a Nuget package that lets you drag and drop a control. However, when a button is dragged, it fires up the click event. How do I pragmatically prevent the button from sending a click event when it is dragged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the MouseDown event to save the position of the button, then use MouseUp to check if it matches what you saved with MouseDown.  If it is the same(meaning the button hasn't moved) then run the code you want on click.